# Merging Python files in .pyc

Tags: python, cpython, pyc

Does anyone know if it is possible to merge multiple python files and depended library in a single .pyc bytecode file?

So that instead of keeping multiple files and I can just interpret the library as a single .pyc bytecode file.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to pack modules into zip? Like it is done here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html

Comment: I mean I would like to do something like compileall, but instead of mutiple files I would like to merge all them in a single *.pyc and can execute all in a single command python *.pyc